# How get my Facebook wall posts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am using Facebook Toolkit.

I have appKey and appSecret, but I dont want that visitor need to conenct to facebook. I will use my login/passwork to get my wall posts. This is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access facebook data without a logged in user's session, you need to create an "infinite session key" for you or the facebook page and set the toolkit's session key property to this. I don't recall the details on how to create so you would need to google this.

It sounds like you are just trying to display a facebook page wall feed on your own website. If this is the case, you could also try using the new graph api. The return format is json. If you can parse/consume json easily, the url to the feed takes the following format:

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed

(Replace cocacola with your pages url details

Comment: Thanks. I dunno why facebook has this step, I need to create a One Time Code by browser, then write a code that I run once to generate the session. Its very wierd.
But worked. I dont use Graph because I need to write too.